# How to get logs in Blackberry webworks

Tags: logging, blackberry, cordova

I am using blackberry webworks and phonegap to develop a blackberry application. I always have to do an alert to get the values. I need to get the logs by something like console.log() or something similar. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use remote web inspector to debug your app: 
[Getting started with Web Inspector](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_testing/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html)

Alternatively, I think you can push alt+lglg on the home screen to get access to the device log.